# Python NN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have struggling so many hours to solve this issue. If you give any advice, it will be much appreciated.

```
#define model 
    
def nn_model_1():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

# Compile model  
    adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model

# Call function here

model_1 = nn_model_1()

# Fit the model and store the history
history_model_1 = model_1.fit(X_train, 
                              y_train,
                              epochs=30,
                              verbose=1,
                              validation_split=0.2,
                              batch_size=128)
```

I want to fit the model but it gives me the following error. I don't know how to solve the issue.

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 10) and (None, 1, 32, 1) are incompatible."
```

Does it mean that I have to check out the initial coding regarding the size

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the comma between validation_split=0.2 and batch_size=128, try:

```
history_model_1 = model_1.fit(X_train, 
                              y_train,
                              epochs=30,
                              verbose=1,
                              validation_split=0.2,
                              batch_size=128)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I correct it but still see an error message.

Comment: "ValueError: Shapes (None, 10) and (None, 1, 32, 1) are incompatible." Does it mean that I have to check out the initial coding regarding the size?

Comment: Most likely, what are the shapes of X_train and y_train? If this is a classification problem, how many classes are there?